# Why wont this simpy "INSERT INTO" query work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-insert

I´m creating a simple register and login system for a school project where you sign up through a form.

This is my code for the sign up process (without the bunch of tests´ that determine if fields were left empty etc.), this is just the query part.

Sorry about the variables containing Danish signs (ÆØÅ), and being in danish, but i have made a couple of tests where it didn´t matter if i used æøå or some other kind of letters.

I simply can´t understand why this little piece of code won´t work:

```
//I retrieve alot of variables from a form

 $Fornavn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Fornavn"]); 
 $Efternavn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Efternavn"]); 
 $Koen = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Koen"]); 
 $Etnicitet = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Etnicitet"]); 
 $Brugernavn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Brugernavn"]);
 $Password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Password"]);
 $Mail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Mail"]);
 $Haarfarve = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Haarfarve"]);
 $Oejenfarve = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Oejenfarve"]);
 $Vaegt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Vaegt"]);
 $Hoejde = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Hoejde"]);

     //The query 

 mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO bruger (Fornavn, Efternavn, Køn, Etnicitet, Brugernavn, Password, Mail, Hårfarve, Øjenfarve, Vaegt, Højde)
VALUES ('$Fornavn', '$Efternavn', '$Koen', '$Etnicitet', '$Brugernavn', '$Password',     '$Mail', '$Haarfarve', '$Oejenfarve', '$Vaegt', '$Hoejde')");
echo $Fornavn;
```

Edit: 
I know it doesn´t work since nothing appears in my mysql database after i run the code.
It just returns zero rows (i use phpmyadmin btw.) And i don´t really get any error messages or anything.

As suggested i have tried to use Mysqli_* for my variables instead:

```
 //I retrieve alot of variables from a form
 $Fornavn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Fornavn"]); 
 $Efternavn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Efternavn"]); 
 $Koen = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Koen"]); 
 $Etnicitet = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Etnicitet"]); 
 $Brugernavn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Brugernavn"]);
 $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Password"]);
 $Mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Mail"]);
 $Haarfarve = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Haarfarve"]);
 $Oejenfarve = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Oejenfarve"]);
 $Vaegt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Vaegt"]);
 $Hoejde = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Hoejde"]);

 //The query
   mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO bruger (Fornavn, Efternavn, Køn, Etnicitet, Brugernavn,   Password, Mail, Hårfarve, Øjenfarve, Vaegt, Højde)
   VALUES ('$Fornavn', '$Efternavn', '$Koen', '$Etnicitet', '$Brugernavn', '$Password',    '$Mail', '$Haarfarve', '$Oejenfarve', '$Vaegt', '$Hoejde')");
   echo $Fornavn;
```

But it doesn´t work.

Everything is stored as "Varchar" in the database with collation "utf8_danish_ci".

Answer to comments:

@John @Jayaram I do not retrieve any error messages, or perhaps i don´t know where they go? Im really new to Mysql and PHP.

@Adunahay Vaegt and Højde are stored as Varchar in the table.

@Gordon The code for the connection is as follows:

```
//We check the connection 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Mads","","meat-market");
//If there is a fail. 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    { 
    echo "<h1> Det er vores fejl:</h1><br /><h2>Kunne ikke forbinde til Databasen:</h2><br /> " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
    }
```

Altough im sure the table exist and the database does since i can see it in Phpmyadmin. The user Mads also has all of the necessary permissions.

@Raphaël I´m not aware if you can use special chars, but i have made a couple of tests before where i tried with special chars and it seemed to work fine.

@dboals I don´t know what you mean (i´m new to php), further explanation would be welcomed.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Do you get an error? What is the error message?

Comment: are `Vaegt` or `Højde` stored as integers in the database? If so, you are passing strings here.

Comment: Although @Adunahay is right about integers and string, MySQL doesn't care, but note that string may result in 0 or 1 generating a notice at database level, bu that's all.

Comment: whats the error message you get ?

Comment: You might not be connected to the database.  The table `bruger` might not exist.  One or more columns in `bruger` might not exist.  You might be entering an invalid duplicate row.  Triggers might reject the insert.  And there are probably dozens of other reasons.  You need to show the error message.

Comment: Maybe stupid, but can you use "special chars" in column names without backticks ?

Comment: recommendation is to  put your query string into a variable like $query_string and print it out then use either phpmyadmin or straight mysql command line and see that your query string works.

Comment: I´ve replied to comments in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you're using `mysql_*` for your POST variables and `mysqli_*` for your DB connection and in your query using `$con` as the first variable, which is `mysqli_*` syntax.

Change:

```
$Fornavn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Fornavn"]);
```

to

```
$Fornavn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Fornavn"]);
```

and do the same for the others.

Sidenote: Use all [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions exclusively for your entire code --- `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions do not mix together.. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

- An example of preparing and binding for `mysqli_` can be found [**HERE**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: I tested it with one of my test tables and added a column called "Hårfarve" with data entered being "Hårfarve_123" and it worked fine. My table's collation is set to "latin1_general_ci" @NotaBird Can you also post your HTML form that you're using with it?

Comment: Another thing you can try is to put this `$con->set_charset("utf8");` just before your INSERT `mysqli_query($con, "INSERT` to read as `$con->set_charset("utf8"); mysqli_query($con, "INSERT...` @NotaBird Or `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');` after your DB connection code.

Comment: For error reporting, try putting `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` or `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your DB connection @NotaBird

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong. 
First off i needed to change mysql_* to mysqli_* in my variables.

But after that it still didn´t work.

Then i tried to change the letters "æ ø å" to something that wasn´t special letters in the database.

It didn´t seem to matter in the variable names tho.

So instead:

- Æ = AE
- Ø = OE
- Å = AA

So apparently special characters are no go, eventough it seems to be a bit inconsistent since i have done it with special characters before... I don´t know if it is dependent of the collaction of the database...

But thanks to everyone!

EDIT!:

I´m using the UTF8_Danish_ci collation in my table and all the rows.

But after this i still had the problem that if i entered a special character in the form, it would show up as A| or something like that in the database.

I have fixed this by doing the following for each variable that comes from the form:

```
 $Fornavn =utf8_decode($_POST["Fornavn"]);
 $Fornavn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Fornavn);
```

And add the following parameter to my FORM tag:

```
accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

Still haven´t been able to execute mysqli queries where the row names contains Æ Ø or Å.